# Instragram web intents to allow favouriting and commenting

Tags: javascript, instagram

Similar to how twitter let you reply & reweet here https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents

Is there a way to do this for commenting and favoriting images on instragram?

I bascially want a link or ajax method which allows both.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [documentation](http://instagram.com/developer).

It seems that currently, the only methods the API exposes are retrieving data via requests, nothing "web based" like twitter intents unfortunately.